# SQL Запросы в php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, printf

Почему у меня не выводит оба запроса а только `$sql2`,как вывести оба

```
$sql = "select message from `messages` ORDER BY id";
        $sql2 = "select id from `messages` ORDER BY id";
         $res = mysql_query($sql);       
        $res2 = mysql_query($sql2);

        if ($res && res2) {
            echo '<ul>';
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($res) &&
                   $row2 = mysql_fetch_object($res2)) {
                $mes = $row->message;
                $mesID = $row2->id;
                $format = 
                    "<li class='logs'>

                <span id='message'>%s</span>  


                <span id='mesID'>%u</span> 

                    </li>";
                printf($format,$mes,$mesID);
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        } else {
            echo "<p><b>Error: " . mysql_error() . "</b></p>";
            exit();
        }
```

Comment: А с какой целью у вас 2 запроса. Может делать это одним запросом `select message, id from messages`

Comment: да, что то я совсем